# How to set a value in a multi-dimensional struct array using a struct pointer?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, struct

I have a struct:

```
typedef struct{
int age;
int height
}Human;
```

I create a multi-dimensional array with that struct:

```
Human human_table[3][2]={ 
{{1,1},{1,1}},
{{1,1},{1,1}},
{{1,1},{1,1}},
};
```

I create a Pointer to the table

```
typedef struct human_table *humanPointer;
```

Now For the question, how can I create a function to modify the table above?

I currently have this:

```
void Modify_Human_age(humanPointer human_table, int x, int y, int New_Age)
{
human_table[x][y]->age=New_Age;
}
```

But I get an error and was looking for help on how to fix the Modify_Human_age function.

Thanks

Comment: What is your error?

Comment: Invalid use of undefined type 'struct human_table' AND dereferencing pointer to incomplete type 'struct human_table'

Comment: `struct human_table` is a name of a type. You never define such type. You define a variable named `human_table`, but it is unrelated to `struct human_table`. Replace all mentions of `struct human_table` with `Human`.

Comment: You are also using your would-be-pointer-to-table incorrectly. You are better off using a pointer to a *single row* instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Never ever hide pointers behind the typedefs. It makes code much harder to maintain and read. So delete that `typedef` from your code.
2. Multidimensional tables in C are in the fact tables of tables. So the 2D table is a table of rows. So id the `X` is a row size and `Y` is number of rows the definition of the array should be `type arr[Y][X]`
3. For indexes and sizes use the correct (`size_t`) type indestead of `int`

```
void Modify_Human_age(size_t x, size_t y, Human (*human_table)[x],  int New_Age)
{
    human_table[y][x].age=New_Age;
}
```